# Inset an object inheriting from a database object does not work in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this object:

```
public class OrderViewModel : ORDERS
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mCountryList { get; set; }

        public OrderViewModel()
        {
            List<string> listCountries = new List<string>();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/countries.xml"));

            var xmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//country");

            if (xmlNodeList != null)
            {
                listCountries.AddRange(from XmlNode node in xmlNodeList select node.InnerText);
            }

            mCountryList = new SelectList(listCountries);
        }

        public void SetCountry(string _country)
        {
            foreach (var selectListItem in mCountryList.Where(_selectListItem => _selectListItem.Value == _country))
            {
                selectListItem.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which inherits from `ORDERS`, an object contained in my database:

```
public DbSet<ORDERS> ORDERS { get; set; }
```

because I wanted to create a new `ORDERS` at this point, but needed the list of countries for user purpose. However when I try to create my order like this:

```
using (MyEntity db = new MyEntity())
{
    if (db.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
    }

    OrderViewModel orderToReturn = new OrderViewModel();

    db.ORDERS.Add((ORDERS)orderToReturn);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'MyApp.ViewModels.OrderViewModel'.
```

What's happening? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues a while back. Using Visual Studio to generate a model for my DB led to all the classes being partial, so rather than inherit to add extra functionality (which I tried and ended up in a mess with) I just added an extra partial for each class I wanted to extend. This keeps EF happy and also means your extra code isn't lost when the model's next updated.

Comment: Thanks, you helped solving my problem :)